# target images with a certain class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

When I click a button, I want to apply some jQuery (let's say **fadeOut**) to the first image with the class **my-image**.

When I click that button again, I want to do the same thing to the *next* occurrence in the markup of an image with the class **my-image**.

The images all appear in various places throughout the markup and are not necessarily siblings.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7):

Though untested, you could take advantage of the **visible** and **first** psuedo-selectors.

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('.my-image:visible:first').fadeOut();
}
```

If your function is one that animates use **not** and **animated** to ensure you don't match one currently fading:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('.my-image:visible:not(:animated):first').fadeOut();
})
```

To refine our understanding of the **filter** method, I just tested long hand as well.

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('.my-image')
    .filter(':visible')
    .not(':animated')
    .filter(':first')
    .fadeOut();
})
```

This is particularly useful during development to quickly comment out various steps:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('.my-image')
    .filter(':visible')
//    .not(':animated')
    .filter(':first')
    .fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: ..and thanks for the question, I've never previously tried to nest psudeos that deep.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two classes. One for the images that were already faded out, and another for those who were not. Like:

```
<img src="" alt="" class="not_faded" />
```

and

```
<img src="" alt="" class="faded" />
```

Now with jQuery you can do the following:

```
$('#mybutton').click (function (){
    $('.not_faded:first').fadeOut (); // your fade out effect
    $('.not_faded:first').attr ('class', 'faded');
});
```

This code gets the first image that belongs the not_faded class and makes the fade out effect. Then changes the class of that image to 'faded'. So the first image of the class not_faded, next time, will be the second one.

Edit: check out Matt's solution, it's more elegant and takes full advantage of jQuery.

Comment: +1 although I would use addClass() and removeClass() instead of attr() in case some other class has already been applied to the image.

Comment: OK, but once I've cycled through all of the images, they've all been set to "faded" so the code no longer does anything, because there are no more "not_faded" elements.  I believe this would be the case for both your and Matt's suggestions.  Any ideas for getting around that?  

I should probably mention that this is for one of those Coda slider showcases.  I have the sliding working, but I want to add a bit more animation to the image that's currently being viewed.